# Differentiation of a norm within a sum

Tags: matlab

I have a function (Thomson problem):

[image]

||x|| is a Euclidean distance here.

x_i & x_j are vectors with dimension D

I want Matlab to expand the whole sum and then differentiate it with respect to x_1_1, then x_1_2... x_1_D, where x_1_1 is the first element of the vector x_1 and x_1_D is the last.

In my code, first of all I tried to compute the expanded sum, and then differentiate it using diff() function, but for some reason my code doesn't work:

```
function [f] = thomson(n,d)
syms x [n d]
f=0
for i=1:(n)
    for j=setdiff(1:n,i)
        f(i)=f(i)+norm(x(i,:)-x(j,:))^(-1)
    end
end
end
```

This is what I get:

```
Error using symengine
Not a square matrix.

Error in sym/privBinaryOp (line 1032)
            Csym = mupadmex(op,args{1}.s, args{2}.s, varargin{:});

Error in  ^  (line 332)
        B = privBinaryOp(A, p, 'symobj::mpower');
```

I know that syms should be avoided, but I am new to Matlab and literally don't know/understand any other way to do it.

Here is the problem that I am trying to code (just in case there is another way to solve it):

1) Given our function f and n unit vectors with dimension D

2) Find a derivative matrix where it's (i,j) entry is a derivative df/dx_i_j

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you explain what the difference is between this question and [the one you posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688591/function-differentiation)? It seems to me that the answer there solves your problem?

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for asking. I got a few ideas from that answers and picture became clearer, but when I actually attempted to implement all of that, received multiple mistakes, which I cannot understand. Therefore, I decided to create a new question with more clear and detailed explanation which also includes my attempt. I never ask questions from laziness, I am just stuck for some reason, been sitting on this problem for a few days.

Comment: Your code does not work. We will likely run into a totally different error as `x` is undefined. As yesterday, it is better if you provide a minimum *working* example

Comment: Try replacing `^` with `.^`.